# instantiate coordinates C#

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

i'm doing a game with unity with RPC networking and i want to spawn player in specific coordinates. Here's new player spawn code:`

```
[RPC]
void JoinPlayer(NetworkViewID newPlayerView, Vector3 pos, NetworkPlayer p)
{
    // instantiate the prefab
    // and set some of its properties

    GameObject newPlayer = Instantiate(playerPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    newPlayer.GetComponent<NetworkView>().viewID = newPlayerView;
    newPlayer.tag = "Player";

    // set the remote player's target to its current location
    // so that non-moving remote player don't move to the origin
    newPlayer.GetComponent<playerController>().target = pos;

    // most importantly, populate the NetworkPlayer
    // structure with the data received from the player
    // this will allow us to ignore updates from ourself

    newPlayer.GetComponent<playerController>().netPlayer = p;

    // the local GameObject for any player is unknown to
    // the server, so it can only send updates for NetworkPlayer
    // IDs - which we need to translate to a player's local
    // GameObject representation

    // to do this, we will add the player to the "players" Hashtable
    // for fast reverse-lookups for player updates
    // Hashtable structure is NetworkPlayer --> GameObject


    players.Add(p,newPlayer);
    `
```

So how  can i spawn a player in specific coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give the object coordinates.

```
GameObject newPlayer = Instantiate(playerPrefab, 
                                   pos, 
                                   Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Using the above code, you call the function `Instantiate()`. The parameters of this method are:

```
static function Instantiate (original : Object, 
                             position : Vector3, 
                             rotation : Quaternion) : Object
```

The `position` parameter is exactly what it says: the position of your newly created object. If you want to see some examples, [click here for the Script Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

So, for example, if you have the coordinates 505, 7, 369, you can add the following line of code above the instantiating code:

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(505, 7, 369);
```

Comment: Okay i'm just a begginer, so how exactly my code sould look like? Let's say coordinates are 505, 7, 369